# Detecting tap to Show/hide UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am kinda new to iPhone development and haven't done anything yet envolving touches.
My view hierarchy like this:

> ```
> UIView - UIImageView - UIScrollView - CustomView
> ```

How do I detect if the user has tapped anywhere on the screen so I can show/hide the navigation bar accordingly? I don't need user interaction on my CustomView but I'd like to ignore touches on the UIScrollView when the user just wants to drag it.

I can already show/hide the navigation bar from my view controller programatically using:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method touchesBegan in UIView to detect the tap, so you will have to have a custom subclass of `UIView` for the viewcontroller's view that you would like to detect taps on. Then you'll have to use the delegate to message your view's controller so it can hide the `navigationBar`.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSUInteger numTaps = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];
    if (numTaps == 1)
    {
        [delegateController tapDidOccur];  
    }
}
```

Comment: This does work. Thank you. Now I'm having a bit of issue assing that event to the delegate itsef. Do I have to extent the UIScrollViewDelegate interface to declare a tapDidOccur method?

Comment: I overrode the delegate @property on my subclass of UIScrollView to implement a "tappable" protocol with my "tapDidOccur" method and it worked fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showHideNavbar:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
[tapGesture release];

-(void) showHideNavbar:(id) sender { // write code to show/hide nav bar here }
```

This is the way to do it using UIGestureRecognizers available on iOS4

Comment: This is a cleaner and more elegant solution if you can afford to target only iOS 4+.

Comment: What's the best place to register this? I'm thinking viewDidAppear.