# Hide/Unhide UINavigationbar when the screen is tapped

Tags: xcode, hide, uinavigationbar

I'm very new with iOS Development and I have just created one of my first apps, in my .xib file I have a `UINavigationBar` that I want to hide/show when a part of the screen is tapped by the user (like in the Photo app). I've found some snippets online but I don't know where and how to use those.

I'd appreciate a lot if somebody could give me detailed informations about how to do this.

Comment: Already asked/answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278527/detecting-tap-to-show-hide-uinavigationbar

Comment: @NathanialWoolls I pasted the code into my ViewController.m but I have the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'delegateController'", how can I fix it? I have to do other things besides paste the code in ViewController.m? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add this toggle method anywhere in your UIViewController. This hides on first tap and shows again in second tap.

```
- (void)toggleNavBar:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    BOOL barsHidden = self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden;
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!barsHidden animated:YES];
}
```

If there is no navigation controller, link the navigation bar with an IBOutlet and replace with

```
- (void)toggleNavBar:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    BOOL barsHidden = self.navBar.hidden;
    self.navBar.hidden = !barsHidden;
}
```

Then add the following in the method `-(void)viewDidLoad {}`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleNavBar:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
[gesture release];
```

If the view where you are going to tap is a UIWebViewController, you have to add the protocol  to the view controller and set it as delegate `gesture.delegate = self;` then add the following:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

This is needed because the UIWebViewController already implements its own gesture recognizers.

Comment: when you say to "replace self.view with the view where I'm going to tap", I have a UIWebView in my app but if I replace self.view with UIWebView I have a warning "Class Method '+addGestureRecognizer:' not found (return types defaults to 'id')". am I doing something wrong? how can I fix it? Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: If you declared a `@property IBOutlet UIWebView *webView`, you should replace self.view with `webView`, but not with `UIWebView` (that's why it says "class method +", you are calling the method on the class, not on the instance).

Comment: Ok, I did everything as you told me: declared my webView in the header file, replaced self.view and I have no errors except some warnings. But when I debug and I tap on the screen the bar is still there!! Here [link](http://www.eddev.eu/mb_prj.zip) I uploaded my Xcode project if you could find a second to take a look and understand what's the matter I'd be very grateful!

Comment: It has multiple problems (and lacks a navigation bar to start with). It's better if you give a step back and start a book from the beginning. This is a good one: "iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide".

Comment: I downloaded the big nerd ranch guide and I'm going to read it, but I'm curious about what you mean with "lacks a navigation bar"... in my project there's a UINavigationbar!

Comment: Sorry, for some reason the project loads in iPad mode only on my machine and didn't notice the iPhone part. Anyway, I edited the answer and uploaded back [the project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5250652/MyBrowser.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you want to send the `-setHidden:` message to your navigation bar. The easiest way to do this is to make an *Outlet* and an *Action* in your in your view controller. Then, in your .xib file, connect the navigation bar to the outlet and some button (even a large, full screen one) to the action.

> Outlets and Actions are basic techniques used over and over in iOS
>   (and Mac) programming, so if you don't understand them, best go read
>   up on them now. Every beginning iOS/Mac programming book covers this
>   topic as does Apple's own [Getting Started guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514) (pay particular
>   attention to the *Configuring the View* section).

Inside your action, send a message to the outlet like so:

```
-(void)myButtonAction:(id)sender{
  [[self myNavigationBarOutlet] setHidden:YES];
}
```

This will hide the navigation bar whenever your button is tapped.

(This assumes you have a `UINavigationBar` in your .xib like you say. These directions will be different if you're working with a `UINavigationController` that manages its own `UINavigationBar`)